# Enable flash/light for panorama photo

Tags: iphone

I couldn't find the flash option in pano mode of iPhone camera

Am I looking at the wrong place? I find the flash option properly in photo and video modes

Comment: pano & flash are kind of mutually-exclusive ideas. Generally panos are landscapes - far too distant for flash to make any difference at all.

Comment: Not at all. Even real estate websites use pano in house photos, people use pano when there are more people that don't fit in a single photo, etc

Comment: iPhone pano works by taking many many photos & stitching them together almost in real-time. Firing the flash for each of those is going to produce odd results. I've never measured the iPhone's flash recharge time, but I'd bet it's nothing like as fast as a professional camera. Most of the time the flash wouldn't be fully charged & you'd get random lighting. Link me to a real-estate pano so I can have a look at how it was probably done.